# Is there a more Electrical-Engineering or Math focused version of/alternative to Minecraft?

Tags: math

So my 6-year-old is a Minecraft maniac.  We play together constantly and have gotten relatively deep into the game.  It's an amazing game and I think the overall effect on him is positive.  But while you can make impressive contraptions and circuits with redstone, it seems like there is kind of a limit to how far you can take it.  Minecraft lacks simple logic gates as primitives for example, or registers, and doesn't have resistors or capacitors or most other standard components.  You can kind of simulate these but it's arduous.  Aside from user-contributed mods, are there any 'official' EE extensions to Minecraft or other fun world-building games that have this?

Comment: This isn't exactly a parenting question (although I understand you're asking it in a parenting _context_) -- perhaps I could migrate it to Arqade (since it's gaming), or Software Recommendations?

Comment: @Erica I see your point, the thing is that ideally I would get input from other like-minded parents who've solved this (as opposed to 12-yr-old CoD jocks, say), I guess that is why my instinct was to post here.  But I defer to your judgment.

Comment: @MattPhillips Whydo you care if it was a parent that solved this.

Comment: @Paparazzi Oh I don't, but I just figured the odds were better from people with a similar perspective.  That's all.

Comment: Have you checked out feed the beast yet? Comes bundled with many mods and new blocks, https://ftb.gamepedia.com/Logic_Gate

Comment: @reinierkors Oh that looks good and maybe 'official' enough to overcome my qualms about 3rd party MC mods.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the FTB packs as mentioned in the comments.
Look for packs marked "tech". They usually contain "automation" type of mods. This could include things such as the ability to grow, harvest and turn canola seeds into bio-fuel to power an automatic mining system.

You can also compile your own mini pack to enable specifically things such as redstone logic circuits and whatnot. I HIGHLY advise checking out "CompuCraft". I'm not sure if it is updated to the latest version of MC, but if not it may even be worth rolling back to whatever version of MC it supports. It enabled players to construct little robots called "turtles" and then program them IN GAME in a real language called Lua.

Also check these individual mods out:

- BluePower
- Project Red
- Redstone Paste
- Super Circuit Maker
- Wireless Redstone
- Integrated Circuits
- Practical Logistics

I haven't used all of them, but many have been in the packs I have played.

You could even grab a modpack from the FTB list, and then add another mod in yourself although you'd need to be aware of the crash potential and check for conflicting IDs.

The FTB forums may also be a good place for more specific advise.

For general additional content and a GREAT challenge (plus it acts a guide to how to use some of the most common mods), it may be worth playing through a "Skyblock" map with your son. Its not focused on tech per say, but they are just great fun. You start (generally) with a block of dirt and a sapling hovering over a void world. Everything can be slowly acquired from the sapling. Trees yield wood for a bigger platform, leaves can be composted for more dirt, dirt can yield stones, etc.

Regarding "official" mods - I don't believe there are ANY. Microsoft now own MC and thanks to the LARGE and active modding community, I don't think they plan to dabble in it. I also really hope they NEVER choose to. Generally any mod with a decent quantity of reviews, maybe something with a wiki, anything featured in a mod-spotlight on youtube, etc; will have had enough people using it that it would have become obvious if there was some sort of security concern. Many mods are also open to contributions and maintained through github so they get checked by many people.

Comment: Just got the Space & Astronomy mod and OMG, mind = blown... though I don't suppose you know a way to load only some but not all mods?  Right now loading takes over a minute even on a fairly modern machine!

Comment: @MattPhillips If it only takes "over a minute" then you must not have many mods loaded! ;)
The packs I play take over 5 min on my comp about about 4 min on my husbands somewhat newer comp.
The RAM usage will be critical in many packs. Go into the settings in the Twitch/FTB loader and give it at least 6+ gb of ram if possible. It may not affect the load time but it will impact the gameplay/load times/lag.

Comment: @MattPhillips for the Q of "some but not all mods"... I don't know how to do that from the ftb loader but if you download the pack and then navigate to it and just delete some mods... you *may* be able to then manually boot that from the normal minecraft loader... I'm just guessing though. Ask around the FTB and/or MC forums and someone will be able to tell you exactly how to do it :)
(don't try my suggestion without backing up your world first..)

Comment: @MattPhillips also be careful of dependencies. Some mods don't seem as if they do much, but they support a variety of other mods. I think ChickenChunks may be one of those but there are others too. Some packs have also had the recipes modified (and/or quests added) that depend on being able to access all mods. Plus removing a mod from an existing world may corrupt your world as blocks generated at world-gen may find themselves undefined.